# SerialPort in C# doesn't send correctly Extended ASCII char

Tags: c#, serial-port, non-ascii-characters

I'm using SerialPort in C# and I discovered that I'm not able to send extended ASCII Characters.

If I send a char lower than 128 it's transmitted correcly, otherwise I transmit always 0x3F

```
comport.Write(((char)127).ToString());  ///I receive 0x7F 
comport.Write(((char)128).ToString());  ///I receive 0x3F
```

Is there a particular setting that allows me to send a char from 0x00 to 0xFF?

Comment: use `byte`.....

Comment: @DanielA.White

if I change to

`comport.Write(((byte)128).ToString());`

I send 3 charachters : '1', '2', '8'

Comment: don't call `.ToString()`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_Write_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8):

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters. ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'. To support additional characters in that range, set Encoding to UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

So you should just change `Encoding` property of `comport` object.

Comment: Thank you!

After some tests I've noticed that the right encoding for me was the following

`comport.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);`